# How to set up Component RTL for Android in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm building mobile app with react-native, and I would like to set up RTL for Android app in react-native.

I know this is the [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps) for setting it up, however, I couldn't understand the following part.

```
Making an App RTL-ready
To support RTL, you should first add the RTL language bundles to your app.

See the general guides from iOS and Android.
Allow RTL layout for your app by calling the allowRTL() function at the beginning of native code. We provided this utility to only apply to an RTL layout when your app is ready. Here is an example:

iOS:

// in AppDelegate.m
     [[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];
Android:

// in MainActivity.java
     I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
     sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(context, true);
```

Especially, I couldn't understand Android part. How can I add the following code into `MainActivity.java`

```
     I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
     sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(context, true);
```

This is my `MainActivity.java`

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "VtuberDayoneApp";
    }
    I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
    sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(context, true);

}
```

And this is the error message that shows up when building the app.

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/xxxx/Documents/projects/company/projectnam/HelloWorld/android/app/src/main/java/com/helloworld/MainActivity.java:16: error: <identifier> expected
    sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(context, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onCreate` function.

```java
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;
...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance(); 
        sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(context, true);
    }
```

Please now re-enable the reaction native. This configuration will need to restart the development process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I got 2 errors. Could you tell me about the value `content`? Where is the content initialized? And should I put `@Override` on the `onCreate()`? Because I got the following error. `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`

Comment: `content` is `getApplicationContext()` The following error is due to SDK version. It appears that there is an interface that needs to be assigned according to the update. Please delete this phrase. `super.onCreate();`